# Magento2 admin panel breaks all of sudden due to javascript errors in console log

Tags: javascript, magento, magento2, admin, adobe-analytics

All of sudden in admin panel there is lots of javascript errors display in console log and sales>order section also not loading properly, side menu is also not clickable sometimes.
[Admin Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pO7rH.png)

The root cause of the problem is Magento_AdminAnalytics module which was causing the problem.
I have disabled it by set the value to no in
Stroes>Configuration>Advanced>Admin>Admin Usage> Enable Admin Usage Tracking
and it works for me.
[Stores Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7rCU.png)